# Relation of Voltage of a line and its cross section area?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, transmission-line

For a given power delivered, if the working voltage of line is raised to n times, then cross sectional area of line conductor would reduced to?

Comment: What does the resistance of a wire depend on? What does Ohm's law say about the voltage and current?

Comment: This sounds like homework so you need to show some effort at answering the question yourself. What do you understand and where are you stuck.